# Class moderncv doesn't work with purple

Tags: color, moderncv

I've only recently started to work with LaTeX.
I've seen the nice CV that it is possible to do with [**`moderncv`**](http://texdoc.ne/pkg/moderncv), however I'm not able to change the color to purple. I do not understand why..
It works with other colors, blue, orange, etc..

```
\moderncvtheme[purple]{casual}
```

Anyone has any idea how to change to purple or why this is happening?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

 % moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[purple]{casual}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}  

\firstname{First Name}
\familyname{Family Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle \\[-4.5em]

\section{Personal details}
\cvline{e-mail}{\small \\[-1.65em]
\cvline{mobile} {\small }\\[-1.65em]
 \cvline{nationality}{\small }\\[-1.65em]
\cvline{date of birth}{\small }\\[-2.5em]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\moderncvtheme[purple]{casual}` works for me, so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using TexMaker..could it be because of that? The problem is instead of purple I have it in blue..

Comment: Using a certain editor isn't likely to be the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `purple` color option was added in version 0.13.0 of `moderncv` (released on November 06 2011).

Depending on what LaTeX distribution you are using (yes, I am looking at Ubuntu < 12.10...), you might still be using a *very* outdated version of `moderncv`. Please check your `.log` to find out if that is the cause of your issue, and update moderncv from [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) or [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/moderncv) accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! In fact that was the problem, I have ubuntu 12.04, I've updated the moderncv (with some difficulties :p) but now it is working. I even have more templates ;) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Your given MWE works for me (after deleting your several `\\[-1.65em]`). If I change your line `\moderncvtheme[purple]{casual}` to `\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}` the color in the documents changes.

I think your used pdf viewer does not show the changing of the color. I suggest you store a purple and a blue CV in two pdf files. Then use Acrobat Reader or SumatraPDF to view the CV and you will see the color changing. It could also be that you have to adjust your screen ...

The changed MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83528/moderncv-doesnt-work-with-purple
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

 % moderncv themes
 \moderncvtheme[purple]{casual} % purple color in CV
%\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}   % blue color in CV
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}  

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Family name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\section{Personal details}
\cvline{e-mail}{\small} 
\cvline{mobile}{\small} 
\cvline{nationality}{\small}  
\cvline{date of birth}{\small}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed @Xavier suggestion and with the new version of moderncv installed all colors work :)